# CSS - Is it safe only to use one @media query when designing for mobile?

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, mobile-website

I'm doing a website that is supposed to work on mobile devices. I have researched about the subject and every website recommends that I use a different media query for each device I intend the website to work on, for example:

```
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {    
}

/* etc... */
```

However I feel it would be much much simpler to just use one media query for landscape and another for portrait orientation, but I haven't found anyone recommending that.

I imagine you may want to design something more specific for tablet. But speaking only about mobile phones, I can only thing of a reason to have different media queries for each device if you want something CRAZY specific.

Is there any reason for it?
Should I add a media query for each device or is it "safe" to continue with only two media queries?

Comment: It really depends on your design, if you can accommodate all your design elements within a specific size, you don't really need several different media queries for each device.

Comment: Short Answer: Yes

Comment: it looked safe but nobody advised to do it anywhere I could find. Better safe than sorry!
Ended up only using a @media query for portrait and another for landscape and smart positioning and sizes for responsiveness as planned. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

That's absolutely fine. Don't forget to add the responsive meta tag to every page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and then use media queries as you resize your preview window width and height. That'll make the website same as the desktop version.

Answer (score 1):

You can totally pull it off with just one or two media queries. I do it all the time for tablet and then for mobile in fully responsive sites that work on all devices. Those type of fleshed out media queries are for very specific sizes when the developer wants to have a set version of the site for this size and that size.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    /* Landscape style changes */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Portrait to mobile style changes */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
   /* Maybe one more because that header text doesn't fit anymore on smaller screen */
}
```

It will be as good the rest of your code, but if you have clean css this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is **NO** problem with it, as far as I see it.

You make your site `Responsive` for not only the browser window (resizing) but also `Adaptive` on specific devices. Adding `and` on those media queries is good too if you see how it behaves (target) on `Android` phones since your breakpoint basis are `iPhone`.

You may consider creating another `.css` file for phone/mobile, the same goes for others (Tablet, TV, etc).

[w3schools - media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Put all your mobile queries on separate `.css`. Facebook did the same `m.facebook.com`.

[image: W3Schools media queries]